# How to make com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton text lower case

Tags: android, material-components-android

How to make the text lowercase for `MaterialButton`? `textAllCaps="false"` is not working for me. I am using `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3`

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_button"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_label_enabled"/>
```

Comment: have you tried `app:textAllCaps="false"` ?

Comment: Thanks, it works just with just app:textAllCaps="false", no need the "android:textAllCaps" one, android studio didn't auto complete for me so I thought that attribute does not exist.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set both `textAllCaps` and `android:textAllCaps` to false to disable all capitalize setting.

Comment: Thanks, it works just with just app:textAllCaps="false", no need the "android:textAllCaps" one, android studio didn't auto complete for me so I thought that attribute does not exist.

Comment: And programmatically in Kotlin, just `button.isAllCaps = false` does the trick.